# HTML Audio Element Disabled With Vue Dynamically Bound Source

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm making a small website for a school project that sells hip hop beats using Vue.js, and I'm making the page that allows you to preview a beat and buy it. I'm using an HTML audio tag for the beat previews. I have the data for each beat including its source, but when I dynamically bind the audio source, the audio element is disabled. However, dev tools shows that the correct source is bound.

When I hard code the source, it works. When other people online dynamically bind an unchanging image or video source, it works for them the same way I'm doing it. I have even put "v-if='beat.source'" in the audio tag and the element appears, so it seems to know the source exists when the page loads.

```html
<div class="beat-block" v-for="beat in beats" v-bind:key="beat.id">
   <h2 class="beat-title">{{ beat.name }}</h2>

   <audio controls class="beat-preview" controlslist="nodownload">
      <source :src="beat.source" :type="beat.type">
   </audio>

   <div class="beat-tags">
      Tags:
      <div class="tags-list" v-for="tag in beat.tags">{{tag}}&nbsp; 
      </div>
   </div>

   <button class="beat-buy" @click="pushPurchase(beat.id)">Buy</button>
</div>
```

```
data: function() {
    return {
      beats: [
        {
          name: "Fruity Beat",
          source: "../assets/beats/fruity.wav",
          type: "audio/wav",
          tags: ["trap", "happy", "upbeat", "bubbly", "playful"],
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Cloud Rap",
          source: "../assets/beats/julia.mp3",
          type: "audio/mp3",
          tags: ["trap", "cloud rap", "spacey", "atmospheric"],
          id: 2
        }
      ]
    };
```

[Here's what a block looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLuaL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw you use relative path `../assets/beats/fruity.wav`, can you try using `require`:

```
<audio controls class="beat-preview" controlslist="nodownload">
   <source :src="getSource(beat)" :type="beat.type">
</audio>
```

and add a method:

```
methods: {
  getSource(beat) {
    return require(beat.source)
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it gives me an error. I also tried passing beat.source into the method and requiring that, but the same thing happens. The error is 
"Error: Cannot find module '/Users/corbinedwards/Documents/E-Commerce/ccj/src/assets/beats/fruity.wav' at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./src/views sync recursive"

However I can copy and paste that exact same path into source and it works without the binding.

Comment: Can you include your webpack config? I think you need to add file-loader or url-loader to webpack config to be able to load mp3 and wav file.